# Getting Exception while running Applet?

Tags: java, applet

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-3" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at oracle.xml.jaxp.JXDocumentBuilder.<init>(JXDocumentBuilder.java:77)
at oracle.xml.jaxp.JXDocumentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder(JXDocumentBuilderFactory.java:132)
at com.alu.sam.common.api.common.ObjectToXML.buildDocumentFromObject(ObjectToXML.java:33)
at com.alu.sam.configgui.common.IMSDataSource.insert(IMSDataSource.java:194)
at com.alu.sam.configgui.common.DataSubmitThread.run(DataSubmitThread.java:1560)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "oracle.xdkjava.compatibility.version" "read")
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.AWTAppletSecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPropertyAccess(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.System.getProperty(Unknown Source)
at oracle.xml.util.XMLUtil$2.run(XMLUtil.java:1104)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at oracle.xml.util.XMLUtil.getProperty(XMLUtil.java:1099)
at oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLParser.<clinit>(XMLParser.java:1249)
```

Can anyone please tel me why i m getting this exception?

Comment: Question is guess the code OR solve the exception you are getting?
Please include code so that we can help you.

Comment: `Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException:` **`access denied`**